# Issue with loading bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar in JNLP

Tags: java, java-web-start, bouncycastle, jnlp

So I am trying to use run a project in JNLP that uses an external jar to provide encryption. When the JNLP is run I get the following Exception

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://localhost:8080/../lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And the following Wrapped Exception

```
java.io.IOException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for org/bouncycastle/...
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToTempFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToCache(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

the jar is question is being specified to the JNLP file as

```
<jar href="lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar"/>
```

With out the jar the project boots just fine, but the parts requiring the encryption fail so I am fairly confident that this is issue with JNLP specification. Any ideas on fixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the signature  from jar's meta-inf and sign it again

Comment: If you just remove the signing and try again, do you get found unsigned entry error? Clean web start cache on every try with javaws -viewer in terminal

Comment: Oh wait I thought I was grabbing a clean unsigned jar, but I wasn't. Your suggestion worked perfectly